# Не получается сделать web-server на ПК

Tags: windows, сервер, wifi, пк

Хочу сделать ПК сервером для чата, сделал статический IP

[image: 1]

Настроил роутер на то, что моё устройство по MAC имеет статический порт

[image: 2]

Открыл этот порт в Port Triggering
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая ОС у вас?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц в метке он указал

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Windows 7 Максимальная, 64-bit

Comment: для каких целей нужен веб сервер? сайт поднять?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц web-chat, пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательнее.

Comment: хорошо. у вас я увидел только настройку роутера (которую скорее всего не нужно было даже трогать). Для чата нужен сервер: из локальных например IIS или DENVER или еще че то....еще для чата могут быть подняты веб сокеты. Поэтому я и спрашиваю какую технологию вы хотите использовать

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц пытаюсь просто открыть через браузер по внешyему ip, и тишина, TCP

Comment: добавьте порт к прослушке

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90780/discussion-between-actticus-and--).

Comment: win+r -> firewall.cpl -> Дополнительные параметры. Правило для входящих -> добавить правило -> для порта -> протокол TCP (если другой то вы должны об этом знать) -> и написать порт вашего локадльного сервера -> далее -> далее -> имя любое (отображаемое) -> готово

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Адреса вида `10.x.x.x` и `192.168.x.x` являются внутренними адресами и не видны за пределами локальной сети. Именно поэтому вы можете ими распоряжаться - они только ваши и никому извне недоступны.

Для выхода в интернет вы используете внешний адрес. Его выделяет ваш провайдер, который и является владельцем вашей подсети Интернета. Ему принадлежит блок глобальных IP, которые он выдает своим клиентам. Адрес он вам выдает на временной основе, и этот адрес периодически меняется (т.н. динамический IP). Для того, чтобы запустить веб сервер, вам нужен постоянный (статический) IP адрес. Статический IP приобретается у провайдера за скромную сумму в районе 150р. ежемесячно.

Теоретически вы можете попробовать ваш сервер и с динамическим, нужно просто узнать [ваш адрес](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) - некоторое время до смены IP ваш сервер будет виден. Но там есть проблема, что для динамических IP провайдер часто закрывает все серверные порты. Так что скорее всего без покупки статического адреса вам не обойтись даже для тестирования.